# How can I create a shaded histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example in base R

```
hist(diamonds$carat,
     col="black",
     density=25,
     angle=60)
```

[image]

I can't make the ggplot version work and I can't find anything in the www:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram() + theme_bw()
```

Background: In most cases I don't print colors, so I would prefer to encode in style rather than fill color.

Comment: There is this package: https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures

Comment: @sindri_baldur Is there nothing ggplot2-internal? I don't need such fancy styles ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reprex that shows one approach using `ggpattern`:

```r
devtools::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +
  stat_bin(geom = "bar_pattern",
           breaks = 0:10 * 0.5,
           fill = "white",
           color = "black", 
           pattern_fill = "gray50",
           pattern_angle = 60,
           pattern_density = 0.3,
           pattern_spacing = 0.01,
           pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, coolbutuseless!! I'd appreciate if they would implement that in ggplot2...